# Unix VPS server going down at almost the same time every day

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, unix, vps

My server load seems to be really spiking and many times the server goes down at the same time each night (Around midnight). I have about 20 cPanel accounts hosted on it and have tried everything I know to try to find what is causing the issue.

Some of the things I have tried:

1. Combined all site access logs found in /etc/httpd/domlogs and cannot see anything unusual at the time of server going down.
2. Checked most other logs in the var/log directory and found nothing indicating the issue at the time the server is going down.
3. Checked cron logs and cannot see anything unusual.. See below. Last night CPU spiked to 7.5 at 00:14.

What else can I be checking? How can I really monitor to find out the root cause?

> Dec  8 00:05:01 v1 crond[6082]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/cpanel/bin/dcpumon >/dev/null 2>&1)
>
> Dec  8 00:05:01 v1 crond[6084]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/cpanel/whostmgr/bin/dnsqueue > /dev/null 2>&1)
>
> Dec  8 00:10:01 v1 crond[6435]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
>
> Dec  8 00:10:01 v1 crond[6436]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/cpanel/bin/dcpumon >/dev/null 2>&1)
>
> Dec  8 00:15:12 v1 crond[6775]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/autorepair recoverymgmt >/dev/null 2>&1)
>
> Dec  8 00:15:12 v1 crond[6776]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/recoverymgmt >/dev/null 2>&1)
>       Dec  8 00:15:12 v1 crond[6777]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/cpanel/bin/dbindex >/dev/null 2>&1)
>
> Dec  8 00:15:12 v1 crond[6781]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/cpanel/bin/dcpumon >/dev/null 2>&1)
>
> Dec  8 00:20:33 v1 crond[7047]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it's a very wide question, but these are the following things you might try doing to find the problem.

1. First thing I am sure of is that this is a specific cron which runs everyday and creating the issue.
2. Then first enable the sar logging, which I believe you have already enabled. If not, then please enable it.
3. Use the sar logs to find the problem area, like check the disk usage, CPU usage and memory usage and try to find that the task which run at that time, is causing what issues, like whether it's using memory, disk or CPU. Though I believe it should be memory, and you are getting our of memory and your system gets hanged.
4. Once you have figured out that main issue, check the crons which you are running around that time, and which is run on daily basis.
5. Once you have few specific cron jobs zeroed down, now check those which might be creating the specific issue, looking at what cron job is doing.

Hopefully by this, you can find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

please check the cron job at the same time that vps go down , it's almost that backup or any

service that running on the same time every day

Comment: did you get a chance to take a look at the cron job log? there is no backup happening at that time i dont believe